# SeriesCoefficient stops working on EllipticTheta in v13.2

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

In `v12`, the following `SeriesCoefficient` computation gives the expected result,

```
1/EllipticTheta[1,z,q]//SeriesCoefficient[#,{z,0,0}]&

(* output *)
(* -((EllipticThetaPrime^(0,1,0))[1,0,q]/(2 EllipticThetaPrime[1,0,q]^2)) *)
```

However, in `v13.2` the same expression only spits out itself, unevaluated,

```
(* output *)
(* SeriesCoefficient[1/EllipticTheta[1, z, q], {z, 0, 0}] *)
```

I have a project which uses extensively this type of computation. Is there are way to reinstate the functionality, or should I simply go back to `v12`?

Comment: it works in V 13.01, but not in 13.1 and after. Notice that [EllipticTheta](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta.html) was updated in V 13.1 and so this will be the cause.  I do not know what the updates are as help just says it was updated. someone else might know.

Comment: Isn't `EllipticThetaPrime^(0,1,0))[1,0,q]` equal to zero anyway? `EllipticTheta(1,z,q)` is an odd function in `z` and therefore its second derivative with respect to `z` should vanish.

Comment: @Roman Yes you are right. I'm just showcasing the functionality provided by `v12`, not concerning about the actual output.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the info! Ok I guess I'll get a different version for now.

Comment: I would call that a bug!

Comment: @bmf Yeah, I reported to Wolfram. Hope it gets fixed!